# Check user permissions not working in template after AJAX refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have strange behavior.

In template I show list of objects as in the picture below. When user add/edit/delete any data by form I update list of users by AJAX.

Problem is that after refresh by AJAX buttons disappear in list. It seems like `{% if perms.foo.do_something %}` don't work with AJAX. What's wrong and how to fix this problem?

*P.S.* In the same time if I refresh page by browser `{% if perms.foo.do_something %}` works perfect. Show permissions correct. I am confused.

At start:
[image]

After refresh list by AJAX:
[image]

Below example of code:
**javascript:**

```
// Submit Form
$(function () {
    var saveForm = function () {
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr("action"),
            data: form.serialize(),
            type: form.attr("method"),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.form_is_valid) {
                    $("#users").html(data.html_users);
                    $("#user-modal").modal("hide");
                }
                else {
                    $("#user-modal .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    };

    // Update User Data
    $("#users").on("click", ".user-edit-btn", loadForm);
    $("#user-modal").on("submit", ".user-edit-form", saveForm);
});
```

**views.py:**

```
class UserEditView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'users/edit_user.html'
    form_class = UserEditForm
    model = User
    permission_required = ('auth.change_user')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        data = dict()
        data['form_is_valid'] = True
        context = {'users': User.objects.order_by('username')}
        data['html_users'] = render_to_string('users/users.html', context)
        return JsonResponse(data)
    ***
```

**users.html:**

```
{% for user in users %}
    <div class="list-group-item" data-id='{{ user.pk }}'>
        {{ user.username }} ({{ user.email }})

        {% if perms.auth.change_user_password %}
            <button class="btn btn-info user-password-change-btn" data-url="{% url 'user:user_password_change' pk=user.pk %}">
                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
            </button>
        {% endif %}

        {% if perms.auth.delete_user %}
            <button class="btn btn-danger user-delete-btn" data-url="{% url 'user:user_delete' pk=user.pk %}">
                <i class="fa fa-ban"></i>
            </button>
        {% endif %}

        {% if perms.auth.change_user %}
            <button class="btn btn-warning user-edit-btn" data-url="{% url 'user:user_edit' pk=user.pk %}">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
            </button>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: my doubt is that your if condition `perms.auth.change_user_password` does not satisfy or it returns false

Comment: Does `perms` in your `context`? It seems `context` only contains `users`.

Comment: @bipen This condition return True when I load page or refresh page. But condition return False when I refresh by AJAX just list of users.

Comment: @Sraw no, I dont have `perms` in `context`. I thought I dont need it. What exactly I need to add to `context`? Also `perms` works perfect when I load page or refresh page. But conditions return False when I refresh by AJAX just list of users (users.html).

Comment: I don't know the whole structure of your project. As far as I can see now, without `perms` in `context`, how could you get access of `perms.auth.xxx`? I think all of them will be an undefined value which would be treated as `False`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.auth.context_processors import PermWrapper
context = {'users': User.objects.order_by('username'),
           'perms': PermWrapper(self.request.user)}
data['html_users'] = render_to_string('users/users.html', context)
```

`perms` in template is a `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.PermWrapper` object,if you want render html by youself,you need pass it to template manual.Doc is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.11/topics/auth/default/#permissions).

Django add perms to context programmed:

1.settings.py

`TEMPLATES->OPTIONS->context_processors->'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth'`

2.code of `'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth'`:

```
def auth(request):
    """
    Returns context variables required by apps that use Django's authentication
    system.

    If there is no 'user' attribute in the request, uses AnonymousUser (from
    django.contrib.auth).
    """
    if hasattr(request, 'user'):
        user = request.user
    else:
        from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
        user = AnonymousUser()

    return {
        'user': user,
        'perms': PermWrapper(user),
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Thanks exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: I have update the reason why you need add perms manual,have a look